# Loss is NaN with small changes in Data

Tags: pytorch

In my PyTorch project I edited my data slightly and now I get nan for `loss.item()` . With the old data it is still calculating a large loss.

New data

[image]

Old data

[image]

Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

A few things that could cause this issue :

1. The learning rate is too large. Try setting a smaller learning rate and see if this solves the issue.
2. You need to normalize your data been fed into the network. You can try
   `X = X - X.mean(axis=0)/X.std(axis=0)` or since the data looks like a numpy array, choose to preprocessed it using scikit-learn before converting to a tensor. Example : MinMaxScaler [1](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler)
3. Try adding a batchnorm layer (eg: `nn.BatchNorm1d`) to your network to stabilize the layer to layer outputs a bit more.
4. Check for outliers in your data (If there are extremely large or nan values) and filter them out.
5. You can debug by setting `torch.autograd.detect_anomaly(True)`